# Insert an equation in word using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word

I wanted to add an equation to Microsoft Word using C#. For example I want to add this:

> The equation is as follows:
>
> $\sqrt{a^2+b^3}$

To do this I used this code:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        _Application oWord;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document oDoc;
        oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        oWord.Visible = true;
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        writep(oDoc, "The equation is as follows:", 16, true);
        oWord.Selection.OMaths.Add(oWord.Selection.Range);
        OMathFunction E = oWord.Selection.OMaths[1].Functions.Add(oWord.Selection.Range,
            WdOMathFunctionType.wdOMathFunctionBox);
        OMathBox B = E.Box;
        B.E.Range.Text = \\ \sqrt{a^2+b^3};
    }
```

Where [writep] is a function which inserts a paragraph in word. Now I have these problems:

1- I can not insert the equation after the text. When I run this code the equation is inserted at the top of the page. I want it to be inserted right after the text in another paragraph with left alignment. I used

2- How to write the equation $\sqrt{a^2+b^3}$ in the equation? Is there any reference showing how the equations are written?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** the 'writep' is as follows:

```
private void writep(_Document oDoc, string text, int font, bool bold)
        {
            Paragraph oPara1;
            oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
            oPara1.Range.Font.Size = font;
            oPara1.Range.Text = text;
            oPara1.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
            oPara1.ReadingOrder = WdReadingOrder.wdReadingOrderRtl;
            int q = 0;
            if (bold)
                q = 1;
            oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = q;
            oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
        }
```

Comment: try using the Office Open XML library rather than the older com library then you can insert straight into the file even with out word running, https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're seeing comes from not specifying any other target position than `Selection`. When you add content to a Word `Range` this doesn't change the `Selection`. So `Selection` doesn't automatically move to the end of content you've added. Thus, the equation is always at the beginning of the document.

If you want the equation to immediately follow the paragraph you insert, then you must get that paragraph, or its Range.

I've changed `writep` to return a Word.Range object, which I use in the calling procedure to collapse the Range to its end-point, then add the equation to that Range.

Note that OMaths.Add requires text content in the Range. So I've put an equation in the Range before creating the OMath object.

Note, also, that I made some changes to your code (how Word objects are declared) so that they work in my test environment, so you won't be able to simply copy/paste.

```
     private Word.Range writep(Word.Document oDoc, string text, int font, bool bold)
     {
        Word.Paragraph oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
        Word.Range rng = oPara1.Range;
        rng.Font.Size = font;
        rng.Text = text;
        rng.Font.Name = "Arial";
        oPara1.ReadingOrder = Word.WdReadingOrder.wdReadingOrderRtl;
        int q = 0;
        if (bold)
            q = 1;
        rng.Font.Bold = q;
        rng.InsertParagraphAfter();

        return rng;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
      Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc;
      Word.Range rng = null;
      oWord.Visible = true;

      oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
      rng = writep(oDoc, "The equation is as follows:", 16, true);
      object oCollapseEnd = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
      rng.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
      rng.Text = "\\sqrt{a^2+b^3}";
      rng.OMaths.Add(rng);
      Word.OMathFunction E = rng.OMaths[1].Functions.Add(rng,
        Word.WdOMathFunctionType.wdOMathFunctionBox);
   }
```